Accessing Azure Blob using sftp protocol using R
I need to download files from an Azure blob storage with sftp support enabled. I have been provided with a username, password and endpoint which works when using filezilla to access the blob.
The issue is that i cant download the files using the ssh, sftp or RCurl libs.
Edit: I got this to work with Python but my prod environment is restricted to R.
Rcurl code:
# Define connection parameters
protocol <- "sftp"
server <- "endpoint.blob.core.windows.net"
user <- "username"
password <- "password"
file <- "/home/folder/file.csv"
url <- paste0(protocol, "://", server, file)

# Download the file    
data <- getURL(url = url, userpwd = paste0(user, ":", password), verbose = TRUE)

error:
Host endpoint.blob.core.windows.net:22 was resolved.
IPv6: (none)
IPv4: 52.xxx.xxx.xx
Trying 52.xxx.xxx.xxx:22...
Connected to endpoint.blob.core.windows.net (52.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 22
Failure establishing ssh session: -5, Unable to exchange encryption keys
Closing connection
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
Failure establishing ssh session: -5, Unable to exchange encryption keys

ssh code:
# Define connection parameters
server <- "endpoint.blob.core.windows.net"
port <- 22
user <- "username"
password <- "password"
file_path <- "/home/folder/file.csv"
local_path <- "."
    
# Establish SFTP connection
sesh <- ssh_connect(paste0(user, "@", server), passwd = password)
    
# Download the file
scp_download(session=sesh, files=file_path, to=local_path, verbose = TRUE)

sesh variable:
<ssh session>
username@endpoint.blob.core.windows.net:22 (connected)
server: 07:af:36:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx

error:
Error: SCP failure: Failed executing command: scp -f -r '/home/folder/file.csv'

sftp code:
# Define connection parameters
urlRemote <- 'endpoint.blob.core.windows.net'
username <- "username"
password <- "password"
    
# Establish SFTP connection
sftp_con <- sftp_connect(server = urlRemote, 
                         folder = "/home/folder", 
                         username = username, 
                         password = password,
                         port=22)
# list files in blob folder    
clientFiles <- sftp_list(sftp_connection = sftp_con,
                         type = "f", 
                         verbose = T)

sftp_con variable:
$protocol
[1] "sftp://"

$server
[1] "endpoint.blob.core.windows.net"

$port
[1] 22

$folder
[1] "home/folder"

$username
[1] "username"

$password
[1] "password"

$userpass
[1] "username:password"

$url
[1] "sftp://endpoint.blob.core.windows.net/home/folder/"

$url_port
[1] "sftp://endpoint.blob.core.windows.net:22/home/folder/"

$login_url
[1] "sftp://username:password@endpoint.blob.core.windows.net/home/folder/"

$login_url_port
[1] "sftp://username:password@endpoint.blob.core.windows.net.blob.core.windows.net:22/home/folder/"

$timeout
[1] 30

error:
SFTP url: sftp://endpoint.blob.core.windows.net/home/folder/
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  :
Failure establishing ssh session: -5, Unable to exchange encryption keys

I usually use the "sftp" lib from this git repo https://github.com/stenevang/sftp for this type of work but it doesnt seem to work for Azure blobs with sftp protocol enabled.

Need to Access Azure Blob using sftp protocol only in R?  but wondering if you might achieve this more easily with Python instead.

Thanks, i can get it working with python but my prod environment is limited to R.


Accessing Azure Blob using sftp protocol using R

Here is the code that downloads file from azure blob storage with SFTP protocol using R language.
Code:
server <- 'venkat8912.blob.core.windows.net'
user <- 'venkat8912.test.venkat'
remote_file <- "data/invoice.pdf"
local_path <- "./prod.pdf"

# Construct the sftp command
sftp_cmd <- paste("sftp", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", 
                  paste0(user, "@", server, ":", remote_file), local_path)

# Execute the command in the system shell
system(sftp_cmd, intern = TRUE)

Output:
source("c:\\Users\\xxx\\xxx\\data.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
venkat8912.test.venkat@venkat8912.blob.core.windows.net's password: 
Connected to venkat8912.blob.core.windows.net.

The above code doesn't used any R library, and the file is downloaded into my local environment.

